# trigger('click') cause “Script is running slowly, do you want to stop it?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a treeview-table like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NPGUx/6/ and I'm using:

```
$('.toggle').trigger('click');
```

to hide all elements onload, the problem is that I have too many rows (like 1000-1500) so that cause that the message "Script is running slowly, do you want to stop it?" appears like three times.

How can I make a better solution to hide all elements?

Comment: Use setTimeout for this, it'll prevent long running loops from the "script running slow" message.

Comment: Thanks but I try it and not work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:-

Change your classes from collapse to expand as you render the records and use this query at the end, to hide all but the 0th level, or hide all the other level tr's while rendering itself.

#### Script

```
 $('tr[data-depth]').not('[data-depth=0]').hide(); // Or just render all tr's but this
      //with display:none css property.
```

Change your filter to avoid filtering from all tr's to this:-

```
      var rootDepth = $(this).closest('tr').data('depth');
      var findChildren = function (tr) {
        var depth = tr.data('depth');
        return tr.nextUntil('[data-depth=' + rootDepth + ']').filter(function(){
          return $(this).data('depth') > depth;
        });
```

#### Html

```
 <tr data-depth="0" class="expand level0"> <!--Instead of collapse-->
    <td><span class="toggle expand"></span>Item 1</td> <!--Instead of collapse-->
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e5YD2/)

Comment: Thanks! That works great for onload, but when I clicked on a child the message appears again

Comment: OK so when you click on a child scipt hangs?

Comment: Yes, only when I click the first child (with data-depth="0")

Comment: I think the problem is on IE8 cause in firefox works good. http://jsfiddle.net/BpnMN/3/

Comment: Your filter is a culprit. As it runs over all trs.

Comment: What filter? Is there any solution or option?'

Comment: `            return tr.nextUntil($('tr').filter(function () {
                return $(this).data('depth') <= depth;
            }));` Here you are looping through every tr for each node selected.

Comment: Instead just try this `var depth = tr.data('depth');
            return tr.nextUntil('[data-depth=' + depth + ']');`

Comment: Updated the answer with FIddle.. See if that helps in any improvement.

Comment: I use this: return tr.nextUntil('[datadepth='+depth+']').filter(function () { return $(this).data('depth') > depth; }); and the message dissappears :D Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the rootDepth not work dunno why, but with depth works perfect. You can edit your answer if you want for someone else in future, and thanks! you made my day.